# Expo OAuth Sign on Microsoft

Tags: azure, react-native, oauth, microsoft-graph-api, expo

I am trying to implement an OAuth log-in via Microsoft using expo. I am receiving this error after logging in:

> AADSTS50020: User account 'xxxxxx@outlook.com' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'Microsoft Services' and cannot access the application '36b16703-xxxxxx'(appname) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

My react-native OAuth code snippet is similar to the one on the expo documentation https://docs.expo.io/guides/authentication/#azure. :

Comment: NOTE: My application is registered on Azure and allows all users with a Microsoft account to log in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your account is a personal account and not in a tenant, so you need to bypass the tenant-level login.  You only need to change the `/tenant id` endpoint to the `/common` endpoint.